# Default values on nested maps in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a JSON configuration file that I want to read with groovy
this file has "defaults" in case one key would be missing because no specific configuration has been added.

json

```
{
  "presets": {
    "default": "preset_default",
    "Team1":{
      "AppName1":{
        "Component1": "preset_team1App1Comp1",
        "default" : "preset_team1App1Default"
      },
      "AppName2":{
        "Component1": "preset_team1App2Comp1",
        "Component2": "preset_team1App2Comp2"
      },
      "default" : "preset_team1Default"
    },
    "Team2":{
      "AppName1":{
        "Component1": "preset_team2App1Comp1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the most groovy way to search for the value and falling back to the outer most "default" key?
here's how I implemented it but I'm not sure this would work:

```
if (presets[appTeam])
    if (presets[appTeam][appName])
        if (presets[appTeam][appName][compName])
            this.preset = presets[appTeam][appName][compName]
        else
            this.preset = presets[appTeam][appName]['default']
    else
        this.preset = presets[appTeam]['default']
else
    this.preset = presets['default']
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way

```
def value(presets, team, app, compt) {
    def defkey = 'default'
    return presets.get(team)?.get(app)?.get(compt) ?: 
           presets.get(team)?.get(app)?.get(defkey) ?:
           presets.get(team)?.get(defkey) ?:
           presets.get(defkey)
}

assert value(presets, 'TeamUnknown', "AppName2", "Component14") == 'preset_default'
assert value(presets, 'Team1', "AppName2", "Component14") == 'preset_team1Default'
assert value(presets, 'Team1', "AppName2", "Component1") == 'preset_team1App2Comp1'
```

Comment: this very neat, thank you

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use "inject" to walk along your keys, and keep track of the latest default seen...  Something like this:

```
def value(Map presets, String... keys) {
    keys.inject([pos: presets, result: presets.default]) { latest, current ->
        def node = latest.pos[current]

        if (node instanceof Map) {
            [pos: node, result: node.default ?: latest.result]
        } else if (node instanceof String) {
            [pos: node, result: node]
        } else if (node == null) {
            [pos: node, result: latest.result]
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No idea what to do with a ${node.class.simpleName}")
        }
    }.result
}
```

Then you can do (with the above example)

```
// Defaults
assert value(presets, 'TeamUnknown', "AppName2", "Component14") == 'preset_default'
assert value(presets, 'Team1', "AppName2", "Component14") == 'preset_team1Default'

// Values
assert value(presets, 'Team1', "AppName2", "Component1") == 'preset_team1App2Comp1'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple generic recursion would help:

```
def input = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText '''{
  "presets": {
    "default": "preset_default",
    "Team1":{
      "AppName1":{
        "Component1": "preset_team1App1Comp1",
        "default" : "preset_team1App1Default"
      },
      "AppName2":{
        "Component1": "preset_team1App2Comp1",
        "Component2": "preset_team1App2Comp2"
      },
      "default" : "preset_team1Default"
    },
    "Team2":{
      "AppName1":{
        "Component1": "preset_team2App1Comp1"
      }
    }
  }
}'''


def findRecursive
findRecursive = { json, List keys, List defaults = [] ->
  if( !json || ( json in String ) || !keys ) return json
  if( json.default ) defaults << json.default
  findRecursive json[ keys.remove( 0 ) ] ?: defaults.last(), keys, defaults
}

assert 'preset_team1App1Comp1' == findRecursive( input.presets, [ 'Team1', 'AppName1', 'Component1' ] )
assert 'preset_team2App1Comp1' == findRecursive( input.presets, [ 'Team2', 'AppName1', 'Component1' ] )
assert 'preset_team1Default' == findRecursive( input.presets, [ 'Team1', 'AppName3', 'Component1' ] )
assert 'preset_default' == findRecursive( input.presets, [ 'Team3' ] )
assert 'preset_default' == findRecursive( input.presets, [ 'Team2', 'AppName2', 'Component1' ] )
```

Comment: `'Team2', 'AppName2', 'Component1'` should return `preset_default` shouldn't it?

Comment: maybe or maybe not. we don't know the actual use-case

Comment: A different version based on yours that passes default down `def findRecursive = { json, String... keys -> { j, String fallback, String... k -> (!j || !k || j instanceof String) ? j ?: fallback : { -> owner.call(j[k[0]], j.default ?: fallback, k.drop(1)) }() }(json, null, keys) }`

Comment: @tim_yates see the update. All your dreams came true :)